# valueChangeListener is not getting called from <h:selectOneRadio> which is placed in side a <h:panelGrid>

Tags: jsf-2

I am facing an issue with h:selectOneRadio's valueChangeListener="#{user.loadYesNo}" 
(I use Mojarra 2-0-8 on Tomcat-7) .
If I remove both the panelGrid enclosing the 'h:selectOneRadio', then the value change litener is getting fired.

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head><title> Starting JSF</title></h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid column="2">
    <h:outputLabel>User Name</h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputText id="loginName" value="#{user.userName}"></h:inputText>
    <h:outputLabel>Password</h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputSecret id="loginPassword" value="#{user.password}"></h:inputSecret>
</h:panelGrid>
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action ="#{user.validateLogin}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="yesNoRadioGrid message"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
<h:panelGrid>
    <h:outputText id ="message" value="#{user.message}"></h:outputText>
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGrid  id="yesNoRadioGrid">
<h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{user.yesNoRadioGridFlag}">
    <h:outputText id ="otherLbl" value="Select Yes or No"></h:outputText>
    <h:selectOneRadio id="yesNoRadio" value ="#{user.yesNoRadio}" valueChangeListener="#{user.loadYesNo}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="1"  itemLabel="YES"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="NO"></f:selectItem>
        <f:ajax event="change" execute="@form" render="userDetailsGrid "></f:ajax>
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>      
<h:message for ="yesNoRadio"> </h:message>
<h:panelGrid  id="userDetailsGrid">
<h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{user.userDetailsGridFlag}">
    <h:outputLabel>Name :</h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputText id="customerName" value="#{user.customerName}"></h:inputText>
    <h:outputLabel>Salary: </h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputText id="customerSalary" value="#{user.customerSalary}"></h:inputText>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>      
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Model+Controller mingled:

```
    package com.jsf.test;
import javax.faces.bean.*;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
@ManagedBean
public class User {

private String userName;
private String password;

private String message; 
private String  customerName;
private String  customerSalary;

private Integer yesNoRadio;

private Boolean yesNoRadioGridFlag;
private Boolean userDetailsGridFlag;

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public String getCustomerName() {
return customerName;
}
public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
this.customerName = customerName;
}
public String getCustomerSalary() {
return customerSalary;
}
public void setCustomerSalary(String customerSalary) {
this.customerSalary = customerSalary;
}

public String getUserName() {
return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
this.userName = userName;
}
public String getPassword() {
return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}
public Integer getYesNoRadio() {
return yesNoRadio;
}
public void setYesNoRadio(Integer yesNoRadio) {
this.yesNoRadio = yesNoRadio;
}
public Boolean getUserDetailsGridFlag() {
return userDetailsGridFlag;
}
public void setUserDetailsGridFlag(Boolean userDetailsGridFlag) {
this.userDetailsGridFlag = userDetailsGridFlag;
}
public Boolean getYesNoRadioGridFlag() {
return yesNoRadioGridFlag;
}
public void setYesNoRadioGridFlag(Boolean yesNoRadioGridFlag) {
this.yesNoRadioGridFlag = yesNoRadioGridFlag;
}

public String validateLogin() {
if (userName.equals("xyz") && password.equals("xyz")) {
    message = "Login Success";
    yesNoRadioGridFlag = true;
} else {
    yesNoRadioGridFlag = false;
    message = "Login Failure";  
}
    return message; 
}
public void loadYesNo(ValueChangeEvent evt){
Integer yesNoValue = (Integer)evt.getNewValue();
setYesNoRadio(yesNoValue);
userDetailsGridFlag = true;

}


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the bean in the view scope in order to retain the underlying condition of the `rendered` attribute for the subsequent requests.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class User {
    // ...
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `valueChangeListener` is intended to be used whenever you want to have a hook on the server side value change event which allows you to have **both** the old value and the new value at your hands. For example, to log an event. It's not intended to perform business actions based on the change. For that you should be using the `listener` attribute of `<f:ajax>` instead.

So, replace

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="yesNoRadio" value ="#{user.yesNoRadio}" valueChangeListener="#{user.loadYesNo}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1"  itemLabel="YES"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="NO"></f:selectItem>
    <f:ajax event="change" execute="@form" render="userDetailsGrid "></f:ajax>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

with

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="yesNoRadio" value ="#{user.yesNoRadio}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1"  itemLabel="YES"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="NO"></f:selectItem>
    <f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{user.loadYesNo}" render="userDetailsGrid"></f:ajax>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

and remove the `ValueChangeEvent` attribute from the method.

Comment: Thx BalusC for quick response...Bu It didn't work. As I mentioned earlier if I remove the panelGrid which hold the rdaio button, it works.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that bit. The bean needs to be put in the view scope. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thankyou BalusC---It worked by just adding @ViewScoped to the managedBean. But ,if I use <f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{user.loadYesNo}"> ,I will get following error  --Caused by: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /Start.xhtml Listener="#{user.loadYesNo}": Method not found: com.jsf.test.User@68bac49a.loadYesNo(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)---

Comment: As said, *"and remove the `ValueChangeEvent` attribute from the method."*