# Execute Backing Bean Action on p:selectOneRadio

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, selectoneradio

I'm using a radio component on which, when selecting an item I want to execute an action on backing bean (not navigate to an outcome page, but to perform some action and then update current page via Ajax). Problem is I can't get the backing bean value change listener action to execute

```
<h:form id="one-radio">
    <p:selectOneRadio layout="grid" 
                    valueChangeListener="#{myBean.selectRadioItem}" >
        <p:ajax process="@this" update="@form" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.radioOptions}" var="radio"
            itemLabel="#{radio.name}" itemValue="#{radio.id}" >
        </f:selectItems>
    </p:selectOneRadio>
</h:form>
```

and the backing bean method...

```
public void selectRadioItem(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    String[] selectedItems = (String[]) event.getNewValue();
    //more...
}
```

is there something wrong in the code which I'm missing? I've used this same structure for select many check box which is working...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14956261/1391249, http://stackoverflow.com/q/9180938/1391249

Comment: What does it mean, "*but to perform some action and then update current page via Ajax*" by the way? Updating **the current page** (via AJAX) refers to something like a synchronous request instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11879138/1391249

Answer (score 4):

Rodrigo, there's a difference between valueChangeListener and a simple method call via ajax.

[Check this answer by BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener) about the difference between `valueChangeListener` and `<f:ajax>`

To solve your problem, you could use the `listener` property of `<p:ajax>`.

OneRadio component is used to receive only one value, if you want to select a list of values, use SelectOneMenu

Try to do the following:

```
<p:selectOneRadio layout="grid" value="#{myBean.radioValue}">
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="@form" listener="#{myBean.selectRadioItem}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.radioOptions}" var="radio"
        itemLabel="#{radio.name}" itemValue="#{radio.id}" >
    </f:selectItems>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

In the backbean, you can remove the event parameter, because the value of the OneRadio component now is a property, which I named as `radioValue`

```
String radioValue;
...
public void selectRadioItem() {
    String selectedItem = this.radioValue; 
//more...
}
```